# How to add Microsoft Edge WebView2 Runtime as prerequisite

Tags: wpf, .net-core, webview2

I have WPF .Net core 3.1 Desktop Application and trying to Add MicrosoftEdgeWebView2Runtime as prerequisite with Clickonce but I'm not able to find in prerequisite list.

[image: prerequisite list]

Thanks in Advance.
Ravi V.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try to follow this [guide](https://github.com/MicrosoftEdge/WebView2Samples/blob/master/SampleApps/WV2DeploymentVSInstallerSample/README.md).

I think that in your case you have download WebView2 installer and place it under, either `Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\ClickOnce Bootstrapper\Packages\`, or `<VS Install Dir>\MSBuild\Microsoft\VisualStudio\BootstrapperPackages\` together with product.xml file where you define how WebView2 should be installed.

Comment: Thanks but I'm getting Error while publishing 
"Microsoft.WebTools.Shared.Exceptions.WebToolsException: Publish has encountered an error. We were unable to determine the cause of the error. Check the output log for more details."

Answer (score 1):

Things seem to have moved on since this question was asked.

I've been digging into this and not found any definitive answers from Microsoft. However, today I noticed the following. I am publishing my .NET application using ClickOnce. I ticked '.NET Desktop Runtime 6' as a prerequisite in the dialog screenshotted in the question, which resulted in the following being added to my .pubxml file:

```
<BootstrapperPackage Include="Microsoft.NetCore.DesktopRuntime.6.0.x64">
  <Install>true</Install>
  <ProductName>.NET Desktop Runtime 6.0.26 (x64)</ProductName>
</BootstrapperPackage>
```

Then I ran the resulting setup.exe in a clean Windows 10 test environment which has Edge installed, but not any WebView runtime. At some point during installation of the .NET 6 runtime, "Microsoft Edge WebView 2 Runtime" also appeared in the Windows 'Apps & features' list!

So I conclude WebView2 is automatically included in newer versions of .NET Desktop Runtime.

Other sources suggest it is installed as a dependency of Office 365, and always present in Windows 11.